# Installing matplotlib for python3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and I need to use `matpltlib` in **Python 3.2.3**. I successfully installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

But now it works only in Python 2.7, which seems to be the default version:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

But python 3 doesn't work:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:33:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
>>>
```

Also, my `python` command seems to be 'broken':

```
$ python
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have pip for python3 installed (possibly called pip3)? Then install all your python3 module through pip3 instead: `pip3 install matplotlib`.

Comment: The broken python command may be(come) an issue for your OS: some system tools probably use `/usr/bin/python`. It's a different problem, so better ask a new question just for that (possibly on askubuntu.com instead).

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the broken command is also preventing me from tryig this, so I'll have to fix that first. `~$ pip3 install matplotlib \n
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: that's easily circumvented by running `~$ python3 <full/path/to/pip3> install matplotlib`.

Comment: iirc you need to install `python3-matplotlib`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, just use

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

There are many packages involved with `matplotlib` and using `apt-get` instead of `pip` this is [the officially recommended approach](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#third-party-distributions-of-matplotlib).

Comment: In case anyone else is stuck with an old version of Ubuntu (12.04 in this question). This (no longer) works. There is no python3-matplotlib. Neither is pip3 available. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

if you are in virtualenv
example: `workon cv  #cv is my virtualenv name`

```
$ workon cv
$ pip install matplotlib
```