# Broken 'python' command

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to [install a python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449195/installing-matplotlib-for-python3-on-ubuntu), and I realized that my `python` command seems to be broken:

```
$ python
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I've been told it could be problematic for the OS aswell (I already noticed the software center is just not working).
How can I fix it and link it to Python 3.2?
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.
Thanks!

Comment: Err how it can be broken, if it's missing? Maybe you lost your PATH?

Comment: Did you checked your unbuntu package manager (e.g. synaptic) python is installed?

Comment: And if your software center is broken, I recommend to fix that problem first.

Comment: @luk32 Then maybe it's missing. How can I find out?

Comment: @ColinO'Coal The thing is, I think it's broken _because_ pythonhas something wrong with it

Comment: @Sean Dude, read the error, it literally says "No such file". I honestly do not know a way, to say better that the file is not there. The only other options that I know, where the file is there, but you get the same error is when you don't have rights to execute it, or try to run 32bit app on 64 system, or vice versa, which would be very very bad if it were your case. To be absolutely sure you can do `which python` or `stat /usr/bin/python`. Also this should be moved to ask ubuntu IMO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but a broken system / system administration. It should be moved to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hum, yeah, the SC based on python. Maybe this will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a broken link.

You can check as below:

```
find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 | grep python | xargs ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   30284 Jun 18  2013 /usr/bin/dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 May  8 16:43 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 May  8 16:43 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2993744 Feb 27 20:24 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

As you can see my `/usr/bin/python` points to `/usr/bin/python2.7` which does exist.

If your `/usr/bin/python` is broken and you have `/usr/bin/python3.2`, do the following:

```
rm /usr/bin/python; ln -s /usr/bin/python3.2 /usr/bin/python
```

This will delete the symlink and create a new one pointing to the right place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked _almost_ perfectly: it initially said 'permission denied' so I had to use `sudo`.